# Cross-domain Ajax call gets no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am trying to invoke a cross-domain web service through jquery call `$.ajax()` The service returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">1.4248</double>
```

If I specify dataType xml (or not specifying anything - jquery guesses correctly), I am getting `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{4030734c-b902-4251-9067-1d1b5b15fc72} Line Number 1, Column 1:` error (looks like nothing is coming back from the service). However, if I specify dataType `jsonp` or `script` - I can see in firebug that everything is coming back correctly; however jquery apparently tries to eval the results and gives me corresponding error (missing semicolon or similar).

Is there a way in jQuery to enable cross-domain call *and* not evaluate it?

Notes:

1. I **know** that the fallback option is to call a program on my server that will invoke the web service and return the result to the browser;
2. I **did** specify crossDomain: true. It doesn't seem to make any difference.
3. "error" function **does** get invoked. But instead of original value "data" contains "parseerror".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross domain ajax is only allowed for JSONP, not XML

In JQuery 1.5 they added the `crossDomain:true` parameter which simply appends a `?callback=>` value to the `url`. If you set that parameter, you must also set `dataType:'json'`. The cross-domain URL must also support JSONP and be serving up your expected data as such.

Comment: wow! in 5 minutes got an answer that already got an upvote :)
Anyway, "only allowed for JSONP" by whom? by browser or by JQuery. In other words, is it the *browser* that tries to parse the result into valid JSON or script? I thought it was JQuery!

Comment: By the browser - it has a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to prevent cross-domain scripts from executing without the user's knowledge. JSONP gets around that by wrapping the external script in a callback function and then executing that function on the client-side. What you could do is setup your external script as JSONP and have JavaScript wrap your XML in a callback, then parse it out once it's received.

Comment: Frankly, I don't quite understand your last comment. I *know* what's same origin policy (SOP) - that's why I emphasized cross-domain. What do you mean by "external script" in this context? Web service? And What do you mean "JSONP gets around that"... Does it instruct the browser to bypass SOP?
Last, what do you mean "setup your external script as JSONP"? change web service to return JSON results, rather than XML? It's public third-party WS. I am consuming the service!

It looks like I will have setup a "proxy" on the server (or convince the service provider to return results in JSON as well).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about YQL. However, I still have fundamental question. If *browser* prevents downloading XML, how does YQL overcome it and why JQuery can't do it by itself? Does it work with some Yahoo server that gets XML from real source and then wraps it in JSON?

Hopefully, I'll get an answer in YQL documentation...

Comment: Because it doesn't allow executable code to be inserted from a cross-domain. JSONP tricks the browser - the external domain wraps their code in a callback function, and then the ajax url includes the `?callback=?` so it's executed by the home script, not the remote script.

Comment: thank you for your patience. I don't quite understand how your posts are relevant to my questions; which must be very frustrating to you. So, it seems that YQL is indeed using Yahoo server (http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql) to proxy web service call. In such case, I will probably opt for using *my* server.

Thanks again for your advice!