# How do I parse this xml via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, api

I have this [url](http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/40.71417/-74.00639) which as you can see returns xml of the New York time....here is my jquery to parse out the localtime from the xml and not getting what i want

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
  refresh();
  function refresh() {
    $j.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/40.71417/-74.00639",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXml
    });
  }
  function parseXml(xml) {
     xmlDoc = $j.parseXML( xml ),
     $xml = $j( xmlDoc ),
     $title = $xml.find( "localtime" );
  }
 ....
 ....
```

I keep getting this error

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{a09f5192-ba1f-fc4e-8b9e-2cb0ed8001d8} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Comment: Add `console.log(xml)` at the beginning of your parseXml() function to check what's wrong with xml returned. I'm a bit suspicious of the ajax request itself: doesn't it try to overcome the cross-domain restrictions?

Comment: Have you added `console.log(xml)` to see if you're getting the expected response? You sure it isn't a Same Origin Policy violation?

Comment: it doesnt make it to my console.log i keep getting this error...in firbug ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a cross domain scripting. Similar issues are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212068/xmlhttprequest-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053995/cross-domain-ajax-call-gets-no-element-found-location-moz-nullprincipal). Use JSONP to make a cross domain request.

Comment: How does one get an XML response to work with a JSONP request?

Comment: You can always put the xml fragment into a JSON object: `{'data': 'xml here'}`

Comment: Not if you don't control the content source.

Comment: You are right. The xml fragment will be returned by the callback function. You have to check if cross domain scripting is enabled server side.