# What means moz-nullprincipal?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Here is a small Javascript. (It is a ‘smallest example’.)

```
<script>
    var now = new Date();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute;
    document.write(now.getHours() + ":" + minute);
</script>
```

This throws the following error in Firefox (16.0.2):

```
nicht wohlgeformt
moz-nullprincipal:{356ab095-a1ae-4ba6-a22c-1df0f260f702}
 if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute;
------------- ⬏
```

(“nicht wohlgeformt”: German, meaning ‘not wellformed’.)

What is the meaning of “moz-nullprincipal”. I didn’t find anything informative about that error. What’s wrong with that line?

Comment: I can not reproduce this on Firefox 15.0.1 *or* 16.0 under Mac OS 10.8.2. This might be a bug with your current config, or maybe a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the keyword "moz-nullprincipal", then the error occurs by Google Toolbar.

> (Japanese)
>   http://st777.seesaa.net/article/139189718.html

The page said you should re-install new version of Google Toolbar.

Comment: I don’t have any Google Toolbar installed.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: The solution seems to be to carefuelly check the add-ons. In my case, the error was caused by the Zotero add-on.

Answer (score 2):

The code is valid, this should work.
moz-nullprincipal is an error trigger by firefox in some json / ajax cross scripting security.
See here : [Cross-domain Ajax call gets no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053995/cross-domain-ajax-call-gets-no-element-found-location-moz-nullprincipal)

Are you sure that the error "not wellformed" and "moz-nullprincipal:{356ab095-a1ae-4ba6-a22c-1df0f260f702}" are related ?

Can you try this way  ?

```
now = new Date();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
if (minute < 10) minute = "0" + minute.toString();
document.write(now.getHours() + ":" + minute);
```

Which version of firefox are you using ? 
Are you using JQuery ?

Comment: Behaves the same. It’s the Zotero add-on. The error even occurs when the line is commented out‼ Removing that add-on, everything works fine.