# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location When I use Interop.Excel For generate an Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, vba, com

I use Interop.Excel library to generate an Excel file,but when I send My request I see this error

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0acbe7aa-8d90-47b2-8a34-2ce0a4ee6557} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

**also I set Full Control permissions for my folder to Everyone.I see this error when i publish my project to server but in local system i do not see any error**

This is my code:

```
public class GenerateExcel
{
    System.Data.DataTable dtCustmer = new System.Data.DataTable();
    object[] query;
    public void CreateExcel<T>(T[] listObj, string fileName, string sheetName = "sheet")
    {
        string generatefileName = fileName + HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ImenBourse"]["userId"];
        dtCustmer = ConvertToDatatable(listObj);
        string newFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(generatefileName + ".xlsx");
        Excel._Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
        Workbooks objBooks = null;
        _Workbook objBook = null;
        Sheets objSheets = null;
        _Worksheet objSheet = null;
        Range objRange = null;
        int row = 1, col = 1;
        try
        {
            objBooks = (Workbooks) objExcel.Workbooks;
            objBook = objBooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            int j = col;
            foreach (DataColumn column in dtCustmer.Columns)
            {
                objSheets = (Sheets) objBook.Worksheets;
                objSheet = (_Worksheet) objSheets.get_Item(1);
                objRange = (Range) objSheet.Cells[row, j];
                objRange.Value2 = column.Caption;
                j++;
            }
            row++;

            int count = dtCustmer.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtCustmer.Rows)
            {
                int k = col;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    objRange = (Range) objSheet.Cells[row, k];
                    objRange.Value2 = dataRow[i].ToString();
                    k++;
                }
                row++;
            }
            objSheet.Name = sheetName;
            object objOpt = Missing.Value;
            Excel.Application excelApp =
                (Application) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            excelApp.Visible = true;

            string workbookPath="";

            //if (!File.Exists(newFilePath))
            //{

                //objBook.SaveAs(newFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
                //    Type.Missing,
                //    Type.Missing,
                //    false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                //    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbookPath = newFilePath;
            //}
            excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            objBook.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            //return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            objExcel = null;
            objBooks = null;
            objBook = null;
            objSheets = null;
            objSheet = null;
            objRange = null;
            ReleaseComObject(objExcel);
            ReleaseComObject(objBooks);
            ReleaseComObject(objBook);
            ReleaseComObject(objSheets);
            ReleaseComObject(objSheet);
            ReleaseComObject(objRange);
        }

    }
    public void ReleaseComObject(object reference)
    {
        try
        {
            while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(reference) <= 0)
            {
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    public static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(T[] list)
    {

        PropertyInfo[] properties = list.GetType().GetElementType().GetProperties();
        DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(properties);
        if (list.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (object o in list)
                FillData(properties, dt, o);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private static DataTable CreateDataTable(PropertyInfo[] properties)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = null;
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
            dt.Columns.Add(attr.DisplayName, pi.PropertyType);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private static void FillData(PropertyInfo[] properties, DataTable dt, Object o)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
            if (dt.Columns.Contains(attr.DisplayName))
            {
                dr[attr.DisplayName] = pi.GetValue(o, null);
            }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that causes this error?

Comment: i sent my code,please refresh

Comment: Great thanks, could you pinpoint the line/area where this error occurs?

Comment: yes,I see this error when I publish on server.In local system I do not see any problem.

Comment: Weird, it looks like [this error may be more to do with how your browser is configured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488564/what-means-moz-nullprincipal), or more likely the part of your code which works with cookies, are you using Firefox? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes I use Firefox and I have not try with another browsers.

Comment: I tried chrome  and I see this error again.

Comment: Looks like it's to do with the part of your code that manipulates cookies, and this is a security feature of the browser, [there's other people on SO who have had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=XML%20Parsing%20Error%3a%20no%20element%20found%20Location%3a%20moz-nullprincipal), you may find it useful